# how to write while loop for file in google shell to plus 3 for each line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQJ76.png)

hello, this is a file I created in google shell. I want to plus three for each line such as the first line will be 699 from 696. I tried to use "while read line; do c="line" c=c+3 "line"; done

Comment: What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
   echo $(($line+3));
done < "$1"
```

After creating it you need to give execution permission to your user:

```
chmod u+x my_script.sh
```

before calling it in the following way:

```
./my_script.sh file.in > file.out
```

the result will be saved in the file.out.

Good luck!

[image: Usage]

**TODO**

*Error management when you do have a line that is not a number, or contains other characters.*

Comment: I am trying on your code. but can I put name1.txt after while loop?

Comment: great!!! :) than if you are satisfied by my answer put it as correct! :)